# Conversion failed when converting '2010-10-14 12:55:13' from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a function as below, where I pass date as varchar and it should return the value as shown below. But its throwing conversion error. please help.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction3(@dateValue varchar) RETURNS varchar
    AS
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @retval varchar(30)
       set @retval=FORMAT(CAST(@dateValue  as datetime) - CAST('04:00' AS datetime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
       RETURN @retval
    END
    go
```

Compiled successfully..

When I ran `select dbo.MyFunction3('2010-10-14 12:55:13'),`

Its giving an error as

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Please assist..

Comment: What is this function supposed to be doing?  I don't see an actual problem statement here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
   create FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction3(@dateValue varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @retval varchar(30)
       set @retval=FORMAT(CAST(@dateValue  as datetime) - CAST('04:00' AS datetime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

       RETURN @retval
    END
    go

    select  dbo.MyFunction3('2010-10-14 12:55:13.000')
```

Comment: @Chanukya, Sorry, forgot to add comment. Reason is code only answer.

Comment: @HoneyBadger then what i need to add explanation that already provided by you for this you can post comment instead of giving down-vote that will not give you encouragement to post answers

Comment: My answer (with explanation) already existed when you posted your answer, so I don't think you should've posted it at all.

Comment: @HoneyBadger when iam editing my answer your answer got posted anyway i wont care if you down vote because who asked the question accepted my answer that enough for me ........

Answer (score 2):

A famous pitfall is not declaring a length when specifying a `varchar`. When you don't define a length, it defaults to 1. This means you only send the value `2` to your function, the rest is truncated. The solution is simply to specify a length:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction3(@dateValue varchar(19)) RETURNS varchar(19)
```